# try catch to return to specific line of code in c#

Tags: c#

I am creating a program in c# that will get the name of item and the amount of quantity of that item,and will compute the overall quantity of the item.

My problem is that whenever I enter an invalid input in the **"Enter the quantity of item:"** ,it goes back to the first line of the code and ask for the item name again, What should I do so I can continue without repeating it to the first line of my code?

I've done many research about my problem but I couldn't found the answer to my problem.

```
try
{
    Console.Write("Enter the name of the item:");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Enter the quantity of item:");
        numOfItm = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        totalItems += numOfItm;
    Console.Write("Enter the price of the item:");
        priceOfItm = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        totalPrice = priceOfItm * numOfItm;
    Console.WriteLine("Total amount for " + name + " is:" + totalPrice);
        totalPriceOfItems += totalPrice;
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid input...");

}
```

This is the whole contex:

This is my whole code.

```
double numOfItm, priceOfItm, totalPriceOfItems=0, discount, totalPrice,totalItems=0;
            string name, compute="";

 while(compute != "total")
            {
try
                    {
                        Console.Write("Enter the name of the item:");
                            name = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write("Enter the quantity of item:");
                            numOfItm = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                            totalItems += numOfItm;
                        Console.Write("Enter the price of the item:");
                            priceOfItm = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                            totalPrice = priceOfItm * numOfItm;
                        Console.WriteLine("Total amount for " + name + " is:" + totalPrice);
                            totalPriceOfItems += totalPrice;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid input...");

                    }

if (compute == "total")
                {
                    discount = (totalPriceOfItems / 100) * 10;
                    Console.WriteLine("The total number of items:" + totalItems);
                    Console.WriteLine("The total amount of all items you purchased:" + totalPriceOfItems);
                    Console.WriteLine("discount amount:" + discount);
                    Console.WriteLine("Total amount to pay:" + (totalPriceOfItems - discount));
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should use an auxiliary method and `TryParse` instead of `Parse`.

Comment: Could you paste the whole context? It looks like you run this code in some loop...

Comment: As you are using `Console.Write(...)` instead of `Console.WriteLine(...)` for your prompts, won't your subsequent parsing be trying to parse the prompt + the response?

Comment: I already posted the whole code.

Answer (score 2):

You may put every parameter input in it's own loop until you get valid value

```
 int quantity;
 while (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out quantity) == false)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Please enter valid quantity");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really avoid splitting the try block for every input, because the catch doesn't know which Parse did fail.

If you insist on a single block, then you can add a state variable that monitors which inputs have succeeded so far.